# Segmentation fault while removing member of array, occurs even on 0 0+1 members

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

this is my second problem today...
This function keeps getting segmentation fault and I have no idea why. The fault occurs at the for where it is supposed to remove an 
Problematic function:

```
void get_available_letters(const char letters_guessed[], char available_letters[]) // aktualizuje zoznam dostupnych pismen
{
    for (int i=0; i < strlen(letters_guessed); i++) //pre kazdy znak z letters_guessed
    {
        for (int y=0; y < strlen(available_letters); y++) //skontroluj s kazdym znakom s available
        {
            if (letters_guessed[i] == available_letters[y]) //ak sa rovnaju
            {
                for (int c=y; c < strlen(available_letters)-1; c++) //zmazanie znaku
                {
                    printf("available letters c(%d) is %c and c+1 is %c\n", c, available_letters[c], available_letters[c+1]);
                    available_letters[c]=available_letters[c+1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Parameters passed:
char letters_guessed[]="a______________"(lenght varies but its only more _)
char available_letters[26]="abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

Code stops at the last command, with c=0 (example)

```
    void hangman()
{
char available_letters[27]="abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz\0"; //correct
//char *available_letters="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //wrong
char letters_guessed[26];
for (int i=0; i < 26; i++)
{
letters_guessed[i]='_';
}
letters_guessed[0]='a'; //example of user input
get_available_letters(letters_guessed, letters_available);
}
```

Comment: What arguments did you pass to this function when you ran this?

Comment: Letters guessed is in this case a single letter followed by a bunch of _ and available letters is an alphabet (basic)

Comment: It is supposed to remove all characters that occur in letters guessed from letters available

Comment: this question is about a runtime problem.  Therefore, to be on-topic, you need to post a [mcve].

Comment: I thought this code is enough, what else do you need?

Comment: @Luk164 An MCVE, arguments/parameters passed.  Results from stepping/inspection with your debugger.  Anything else you found out from, say, inserting printf() to log your array indexing.

Comment: Also, simplify over-complex statements and expressions to ease debugging.  Use temporary local vars, eg :  'int availLen=strlen(available_letters);'  printf() them ouit or inspect them with your debugger.

Comment: I gave you my inputs passed to function, if you need I can modify it with no inputs and everytthing static.